# Kotlin example with MQTT and AWS certs

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kotlin, aws-sdk, x509

I have been supplied 4 files from AWS IOT:

1. CA.pem
2. AWS-private.pem.crt
3. private.pem.key
4. public.pem.key

I have tried a multitude of methods to get these to work with Android Studio and Kotlin to connect to an MQTT service and have now lost direction.

Firstly are there any command lines that I need to run on the certs and keys before I use ?

Do I need to use a keystore ?
If so should that keystore be bouncycastle or spongycastle ?
I have tried to create a keystore by running the keytool and creating

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ks.p12 -inkey -in my.pem -name mykeystore
```

but when I try to import like so

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ks.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore ks.bks -deststoretype BKS --provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -–providerpath ~/Downloads/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar
```

I get this error

```
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: Unrecognized keystore format: null
```

So I can't even get testing my Kotlin to see if the BKS works.